# Ceph installs without init scipts. How do I get them?

Tags: centos, bash, centos7, init.d, ceph

I have installed ceph in 3 centos7 nodes with `ceph-deploy` tool. All works good but I haven't any script to manage ceph or radosgw. 
My `/etc/init.d/` folder contains only these:
`functions`, `network`, `netconsole`, `rdbmap`.
Nothing else. So I can not run this scipt:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/ceph-radosgw start
```

because I have not it.
`yum install ceph-radosgw` shows that I have already installed it.
`ceph -s` shows `HEALTH_OK`. 3 mon, 3 osd up and in.
What I have to do to get ceph init scripts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

initd has been replaced in CentOS7 with `systemd`. The systemd command to is `systemctl`. You should be able to start, stop, etc service by using the `systemctl` command. To start `ceph-radosgw` service you would need to run something like this:

`systemctl start ceph-radosgw`